# Migrate Azure DevOps Git repos from one organization to another organization with all the histories, tags and pull requests

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request, dvcs, gitversion

How do I migrate Azure DevOps Git repos from one organization to another organization with all the histories, tags and pull requests?

I tried multiple options to import all the data like

1. Azure DevOps import repository
2. ```
   git clone --mirror old repos
   git push to new repos
   ```
3. ```
   git clone --bare old repos
   git push new repos
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Repo history is easy.

```
git clone --bare <old repo uri>
git push --mirror <new repo uri>
```

Pull requests are impossible. There is no mechanism to export them, and the REST APIs don't give enough options to migrate them with any degree of fidelity.

Comment: Daniel - Really appreciate ur answer but we could export using RestApi but have not idea how to import them.

Comment: @sunilGupta Exactly. You can query the current state of a PR, but you can't query the history of each discrete action against a PR and replay it against another account, and you can't import the current state of a PR. There's no API that allows it.

Comment: Shut, I was hoping for a different answer...

Comment: What will happen with old users assigned in the old repo once they are migrated to the new organization where these users are not there?

Comment: Git doesn't operate on "users" in the same sense as Azure DevOps does; all Git tracks are the committer's name and email address. So nothing happens to older committers; their commits still show in the repo under the identity that they committed with.